# Solid Lipid Nanoparticles

Tags: lipids

Are solid lipid nanoparticles (SLN's) used in clinical practice today, or do they remain only in research?
Specifically for topical applications.

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require some degree of prior research when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Answer (score 2):

For more than 50 years, liposomes have been recognized as a powerful medical tool. It can encapsulate drugs and controllably deliver drugs to specific locations in the body, which makes it useful for the treatment of various diseases. At present, many lipid nanoparticle drug preparations have been approved and used in the clinic.

[Application of Lipid Nanoparticles In Vaccine And Drug Delivery](https://www.biochempeg.com/article/283.html)